# GCD timer suspend suddenly?

Tags: timer

[image]

I create timer use dispatch_source_t,and run the app in background.Then i checked th logs,found the timer suspend for a while,why?

Comment: Well, it was suspended because it was suspended. There really isn't anything else anyone here can tell you. Care to post some code? Did perhaps the machine reboot? Service/app restarted? Busy OS?

Comment: self.timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, self.queueShowAlertList); 
        uint64_t interval = 1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC;
        dispatch_source_set_timer(self.timer, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, interval, 0);
        dispatch_source_set_event_handler(self.timer, ^{
            [self handlelist];
        });
        dispatch_resume(self.timer);

Comment: I create timer with GCD as usual.Why suspend and why resume?The device just lock.Thanks.